# can't open file 'C:\Users\Muddasar': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

I am unable to fix this problem. I accessing the python file after entering cmd within the folder. but still not working. Please help me to resolve this issue.
[image: the screenshot is attached.]

Comment: put doublequotes around the file path. the space is breaking the path

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the folder on your desktop contains a space. Because of this, you have to put the path in quotes, so it is treated as 1 parameter. So command `python "c:\path with space\script.py" ...`, or alternatively use relative paths.

For example `python .\OSM_randomtrips\randomtrips.py ...` where ... is the rest of the command

Answer (score 0):

just put the randomTrips.py file in where your are calling the python cmd.

As randomTrips.py file is in tools and not in base folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).